# php fetch file content and print it out formatted

Tags: php, html, printing

How can i print out an formatted HTML file ? This is my current code:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url));
```

But the result looks so ugly, all sticks together, no space no tabs.
Is there any way to print the file exactly like the original file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-tag would work.

```
<pre>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url)); ?>
</pre>
```